# iOS NSMutableArray value turns to nil after leaving AlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm writing an app for iOS 9.0 and I've run into an error I can't solve to save my life! In short, when I add an item to *NSMutableArray wishlist* in the AlertView, wishlist contains all its elements including the newly added one. However, when I call *[self.tableView reloadData]*, SOMETIMES that the new value has all its member data set to nil. To be clear, *wishlist* in *...reloadData...* does have n+1 elements, but the last one is SOMETIMES nil.

For example, adding an object with the food_item parameter "test" or "test 1" works just fine. But entering "test 2 2 a" results in the data being set to nil upon reloading.

I have tried to solve this by making *wishlist* a strong,nonatomic property in my .h file, but that did not work. I can confirm that the database side of things is working perfectly well because if I reset all the values in *wishlist* before reloading the tableview data, all my elements are there (but this causes some nasty lag).

Any ideas?

```
#import "WishlistViewController.h"
#import "usersDAO.h"
#import "wishlistitemDAO.h"
#import "wishlistDAO.h"
#import "TabBarController.h"
#import "MGSwipeButton.h"
#import "MGSwipeTableCell.h"

@interface WishlistViewController ()

@end

@implementation WishlistViewController{
    NSMutableArray *wishlist;
}
@synthesize username, house_name, house_id, navBar, admin;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    TabBarController *tabBar = (TabBarController *)self.tabBarController;
    self.username = tabBar.username;
    self.house_id = tabBar.house_id;
    self.house_name = tabBar.house_name;
    self.admin = tabBar.admin;

    wishlistitemDAO *wliDAO = [wishlistitemDAO new];
    wishlistDAO *wlDAO = [wishlistDAO new];
    self->wishlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    wlDAO.id = [wlDAO getCurrentWishlistFromHouseId:house_id];
    self->wishlist = [wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [wishlist count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    wishlistitemDAO *wliDAO = [wishlistitemDAO new];

    static NSString * reuseIdentifier = @"programmaticCell";
    MGSwipeTableCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MGSwipeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [wliDAO getFoodItem:[wishlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    //configure left buttons
    cell.leftButtons = @[[MGSwipeButton
                          buttonWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[wliDAO getQuantity:[wishlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]
                          backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] setClickable:false],
                         [MGSwipeButton
                          buttonWithTitle:@"" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbs-up.png"] backgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]],
                         [MGSwipeButton
                          buttonWithTitle:@"" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbs-down.png"] backgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]
                         ];
    cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition3D;

    if([admin isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){
        //configure right buttons
        cell.rightButtons = @[[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                                                icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash-can.png"] backgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                                callback:^BOOL(MGSwipeTableCell *sender) {
                                                    wishlistitemDAO *wliDAO = [wishlistitemDAO new];
                                                    [wliDAO removeItemFromWishlist:[wliDAO getId:[wishlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
                                                    [self->wishlist removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                                                    //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                    return 1;
                                                }],
                              [MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                                                icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping-cart-add.png"] backgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]
                                                ]
                              ];
        cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition3D;
    }

    return cell;


}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"wishlistLogoutSegue"]){

    }
}

- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
    //alert view
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle: @"New Item"
                            message: @""
                            delegate: self
                            cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                            otherButtonTitles: @"Add",nil];

    message.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:false];
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"Item Name"];
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:1] setPlaceholder:@"Quantity"];
    [message show];
}

//which button was clicked by the user
-(void)alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch(buttonIndex) {
        case 0:{
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            UITextField *food_item =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex: 0];
            UITextField *quantity  =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
            wishlistitemDAO *wliDAO = [wishlistitemDAO new];
            wishlistDAO *wlDAO = [wishlistDAO new];

            NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
            NSNumber *n = [f numberFromString:quantity.text];

            [wliDAO addWishlistItem:food_item.text withQuantity:n toWishlistId:[wlDAO getCurrentWishlistFromHouseId:house_id]];
            wlDAO.id = [wlDAO getCurrentWishlistFromHouseId:house_id];

            [wishlist addObject:[[wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id] lastObject]];

            [self.tableView reloadData];


            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

}
@end
```

Comment: You are assigning the ivar to the result of [wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id], which may be nil or not mutable.  The initial ivar assignment is getting blown away.  If that does return a reference to an NSMutableArray, and the source modifies it externally, then since you just have a reference to it it will change your data too.  You might want ```self->wishlist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id]];``` which creates a copy of the array with the data at that time, and handles nil as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the function handles empty results, so if anything, it will return an empty NSMutableArray. Also, I can confirm that it is indeed returning a value, but somewhere between setting it in AlertView and displaying it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it is being lost.

Comment: Right, and if other code has a reference to that same NSMutableArray instance, and that other code then empties or otherwise modifies that same instance, then your reference will be emptied too.  If you care about the contents of the array versus that particular NSMutableArray instance, then make a copy as it is coming in.  After that, the only code which could modify the contents of your ivar is your own class' code.  Right now it's theoretically possible that other code can modify your ivar's NSMutableArray instance.  If none of the above code can be doing it, other code may be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's weird to access members like `wishlist` using `self->wishlist`, remove `self->` since `wishlist` *on its own* refers to it within methods of that class. It acts like a strong property. But since you're already using properties for `username` etc., it's better to make `wishlist` a property instead and be consistent:

```
@interface WishlistViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *wishlist
@end

@implementation WishlistViewController

// @synthesize line is redundant since 2012

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
```

(In code of yours I'm quoting below, I'm assuming you've done this and I'm replacing `self->` with `self.` because the former hurts my brain to type or even look at.)

Now for the the answer, [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1754225/carl-lindberg) is indeed correct when he mentions the `viewDidLoad` lines that assign `wishlist`. It's clear you probably have some misconceptions because you're creating an array, then replacing it 2 lines later:

```
self.wishlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // CREATE
wlDAO.id = [wlDAO getCurrentWishlistFromHouseId:house_id];
self.wishlist = [wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id]; // STOMP
```

What you probably mean to do is to fill your array with results from your `wishlistDAO`, like:

```
self.wishlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
wlDAO.id = [wlDAO getCurrentWishlistFromHouseId:house_id];
[self.wishlist addObjectsFromArray:[wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id]];
```

But you can also remove the first `wishlist =` line and make a mutable copy of the method's result like Carl suggests, however it's less wordy to do it like `self.wishlist = [wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id].mutableCopy;`

What's probably happening is `wishlistDAO`'s is returning its internal mutable array, one it might use & change later, and this is what `wishlist` gets set to, ie. set as a reference to, ie. the same pointer value to `wishlistDAO`'s own `NSMutableArray` object. That's bad and it's what's fixed by the suggested change above. Then in your call later to the same method again:

```
[wishlist addObject:[[wliDAO getWishlistItemsWithWishlistId:wlDAO.id] lastObject]];
```

I'm guessing it starts by erasing its array, which erases yours because it's the same object. Maybe it also releases it and creates a new one in the process, leaving `wishlist` as the only retain of a now empty array.

To be safe & up to snuff with best practices:

1. `getWishlistItems` should return a fresh copy of an array, not a reference to some internal property, or in any other way one that it might change after it's returned. The method's result should be declared as a non-mutable `NSArray`.
2. as suggested above, your view controller should either use `addObjectsFromArray` on the result from that method, or assign `wishlist` to a `mutableCopy` of it.

Doing either one alone should fix your issue. It's a combination of making those 2 mistakes that are surely the cause.